# Brings back only first data point out of 20 possible on page(BeautifulSoup Scraping)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, containers

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xlsxwriter

number = 1
counter = 0
row = 0
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('try002.xlsx')
sheet = wb.add_worksheet()
while number <= 150:
    url = "https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/houston_tx/photo-1/sort-activelistings/pg-{}".format(number)
    base = 'https://www.realtor.com'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    container = soup.find_all('ul', class_='jsx-1526930885')
    # print(container)
    for con in container:
        try:
            name = con.find('div', class_='jsx-2987058905 agent-name text-bold').text
        except:
            name = 'no price found'
        try:
            pnumber = con.find('div', class_='jsx-2987058905 agent-phone hidden-xs hidden-xxs').text
        except:
            pnumber = 'no type found'
        sheet.write(row, 0, name)
        sheet.write(row, 1, pnumber)
        counter += 1
        row += 1
        print(counter)
    number += 1
    print(url)
wb.close()
```

Because the names and numbers are held under the same class and div and such IDs, I would expect it to bring back all 20 per page, but it only brings back the first, how can I bring all 20 back. As shown in photo, all 20 realtors per page are in the same class identity, and their name and numbers are also in the same class. How can I make it return all values in those classes not just the first set?[Each Subtree is one of the realtor pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k37HC.png)

Answer (score 1):

The class `jsx-1526930885` seems to be specific to an agent - so you will probably not find anyone else's listings with it. You could try targeting the `data-testid` attribute instead.

```py
    container = soup.find_all('div', {'data-testid': 'component-agentCard'})
```

And you should remove that class inside the `for` loop as well - just go with `con.find('div', {'class': 'agent-name'})` and `con.find('div', {'class': 'agent-phone'})` instead.

For **example**:

```py
for con in soup.find_all('div', {'data-testid': 'component-agentCard'}):
    print({kk: t.get_text(' ').strip() if t else None for kk, t in [
        (k ,con.find('div', {'class':f'agent-{k}'})) for k in ['name', 'phone']
    ]})
```

prints

> ```py
> {'name': 'Christopher Marti', 'phone': '(830) 660-1004'}
> {'name': 'Matthew Guzman', 'phone': '(281) 650-0533'}
> {'name': 'Adam Olsen', 'phone': '(936) 689-9123'}
> {'name': 'Cyndi Kornegay', 'phone': '(713) 952-6767'}
> {'name': 'The Gayden Team Team', 'phone': '(832) 692-2000'}
> {'name': 'Christy Buck', 'phone': '(832) 264-8934'}
> {'name': 'Tammy Fruge', 'phone': '(281) 709-5124'}
> {'name': 'Todd Spencer', 'phone': '(512) 665-3747'}
> {'name': 'JOHN PRELL, Broker', 'phone': '(214) 696-4663'}
> {'name': 'Rene Sorola', 'phone': '(832) 816-4673'}
> {'name': 'Wendy Cline Team', 'phone': '(281) 858-3451'}
> {'name': 'Andrea Kitzmann', 'phone': '(979) 217-1722'}
> {'name': 'Tammie Bell', 'phone': '(979) 292-6163'}
> {'name': 'Mike Seder', 'phone': '(713) 806-6796'}
> {'name': 'Scott Laird Team', 'phone': '(281) 339-1800'}
> {'name': 'Cari Goeke Team', 'phone': '(979) 530-2714'}
> {'name': 'Travis Edmunds', 'phone': '(281) 363-2500'}
> {'name': 'Libby Mitchell Team', 'phone': '(409) 718-1933'}
> {'name': 'Robbie Jansky', 'phone': '(361) 293-8759'}
> {'name': 'Ronnie Matthews Team', 'phone': '(281) 440-7900'}
> ```

for [/pg-1](https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/houston_tx/photo-1/sort-activelistings/pg-1).